# Number consists of 17 digits, other number is first number in reverse order. Prove that their sum has at least one even digit

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

My thought was that it doesn't matter, whatever is it 17 digits in this problem, or any other odd number.

So for simplicity we can think of 3 digits number.

```
k1 k2 k3
k3 k2 k1
```

Points that $\lceil k/2 \rceil$ should be even.

However, it is true only in case when there is not such pair, which sum is bigger than 9.

Comment: For three-digit numbers, $627 + 726 = 1353$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the digits be $d_1$ through $d_{17}$, and suppose that every digit in the sum is odd. The addition is shown below. In the middle we have $d_9+d_9$, which will yield an even digit unless there is a carry from the column to the right, $d_8+d_{10}$; I’ve indicated this carry with a $c$ below the line. This means that the column to the left, $d_{10}+d_8$, must produce a carry to be added to the $d_{11}+d_7$ column to *its* left; this is again indicated by a $c$ below the line.

In order for $d_{11}+d_7$ plus the carry to yield an odd digit, $d_{11}+d_7$ must yield an even digit. This means that there must be a carry into the $d_7+d_{11}$ column from the $d_6+d_{12}$ column, and again I’ve indicated it with a $c$ below the line. Since $d_6+d_{12}$ produces a carry, so does $d_{12}+d_6$, and there is a carry in the $d_{13}+d_5$ column. This means that $d_5+d_{13}$ by itself yields an even digit, so there must be a carry into that column from the $d_4+d_{14}$ column. The $d_{14}+d_4$ column then produces a carry into the $d_{15}+d_3$ column, so $d_3+d_{15}$ yields an even digit, and there must be a carry from the $d_2+d_{16}$ column. The $d_{16}+d_2$ column therefore produces a carry into the $d_{17}+d_1$ column, completing the table.

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
d_{17}&d_{16}&d_{15}&d_{14}&d_{13}&d_{12}&d_{11}&d_{10}&d_9&d_8&d_7&d_6&d_5&d_4&d_3&d_2&d_1\\
d_1&d_2&d_3&d_4&d_5&d_6&d_7&d_8&d_9&d_{10}&d_{11}&d_{12}&d_{13}&d_{14}&d_{15}&d_{16}&d_{17}\\ \hline
c&&c&&c&&c&&c&&c&&c&&c
\end{array}$$

But now we have a contradiction: $d_1+d_{17}$ must yield an odd digit at the righthand end of the sum, so $d_{17}+d_1$ plus the carry must yield an even digit in the $17$-th column from the right.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply based on parity.

If there would have been an even numbers of digits then you could easily made a number with alternating $odd$ and $even$ numbers (as digits) so that all the digits in sum are always odd. But when you have odd number of digits i.e. $17$ (as in your case), it doesn't matter weather you reverse the order or not, the $9$th digit will always be same.

Comment: but what if sum of 8th pair of digits is bigger than 9, then it passes 1 to 9th pair and their sum happens to be odd.

Comment: The $3$-digit example given by **Abstraction** in a comment under the question shows that this argument is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I came up with formal proof.

Let us have $k_1 ... k_{17}$.

Imagine that $K$ + $K_r$ (where r states reversed) consists only of odd numbers.

Consider the case, when $k_1$ + $k_{17} < 10$

That would mean that pair $k_8$ and $k_{10}$ is greater than 10, as it makes pair $k_9$ + $k_9$ odd by passing a 1 to it. However, that would also mean, that pair $k_7$ and $k_{11}$ passes 1 to next pair, and it can be odd if only $k_{11}$ + $k_7$ is also passed 1 by previous pair. Eventually it turns out that $k_1 + k_{17} \geq 10$. **Contradiction**.

Consider the case, when $k_1$ + $k_{17} \geq 10$.

Then pair $k_{16}$ and $k_2$ should be less then 10. Then pair $k_3$ $k_{16}$ should be bigger than 10. Eventually it turns out that pair $k_{10}$, $k_8$ is less than 10, and $k_9 + k_9$ is odd. **Contradiction**.

Comment: You have the right basic idea, but it doesn’t matter whether the sum has $17$ or $18$ digits. Once you work out where the carries have to be, it turns out that $d_1+d_{17}$ has to be both odd and even, which is of course impossible.

Answer (score 0):

We will try to get odd numbers in the sum of number as far as possible.
Let the number be
A B C D E F G H (J) K L M N P Q R S
+
S R Q P N M L K (J) H G F E D C B A

---

(i) Middle digit has to be same in the number and its reverse. In this case J.
(ii) Now we start from the middle.
J + J = 2J will always be even.
(iii) To make it odd, 1 has to be carried from its next digits addition. Which means K+H has to be Odd and  > 10  (with or without a carry from previous). Hence H+K will have to be more than 10. So 1 will be carried to G+L.
(iv) This means G+L has to be originally Even. With 1 carry, it becomes Odd.
(v) Since L+G is even, it requires 1 carry from its previous digits sum i.e M+F to become odd. So M+ F is odd and more than 10 ( with/without carry)
(vi) This sequencing continues and with the same reason we find that C+Q is even and R+B ( and B+R) is odd and more than 10.
(vii) If we stop here and consider it as 15 digit number, then it is possible to have all odd numbers( see example below)
(viii) But with one more digit each side  , NOW Sum of last two digits i.e S+A has to be odd. And hence A+S also has to be odd. But unfortunately since B+R is more than 10, it will give 1 carry to A+S and make it even.
(Max carry in addition of two single digit numbers can't be more than one)

So in all combinations, at least one digit of the sum will be even. Can't avoid that.
However, if we stop one digit short i.e in a 15 digit number ( as mentioned in sl vii) it is possible to have all odd digits in the sum.
eg        849284746274625
         + 526472647482948
         _____________________
           1375757393757573

It will be true ( get sum without even digits) in all cases of 3,7,11,15 digit numbers but NOT in 1,5,9,13 or 17 digit numbers